# Is ‘platform’ used correctly in the intended sense in this context?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context

> Dating websites and dating apps are today very popular, but we don’t
> know how successful finding relationship via such **platforms** is. What percent of those using **dating platforms** find the right partner?

Some senses of ‘platform’ are programme, stage, stand, and alike. But I am not sure if it is the best choice in the above context. Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/platform):

> 6 b an application or website that serves as a base from which a service is provided.
>
> *music streaming platforms*
>
> … *has built a cloud-computing platform for use by others.*
> — The Economist
>
> … *billions of photos scraped from Facebook and other social media platforms.*
> — C. J. Ciaramella